# nHibernate - IStatelessSession and FetchMany returning multiple parent records

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have the following linq statement:

```
var query = from p in session.Query<Parent>().FetchMany(x => x.Children)
            select p;
```

I end up with a new Parent object for each Child in Children.  So if i had 5 Children, I would get 5 separate, but identical, Parent objects back.  Is this the intended behavior?  If i use ISession, I get 1 Parent as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected, because Stateless Sessions do not track objects; therefore each row results in a new instance.

Comment: This is interesting, I knew it didn't track sessions, but didn't realize that this would be a side effect.

Comment: I figured this was what was going on.  It would be nice to see this behavior changed for single queries.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do a `Distinct` call on the query?

```
var results = query.Distinct();
```